# Where RSA is used?

Tags: rsa, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

Someone please state two or three applications of RSA algorithm. I heard that RSA is used for SSL. Is that true?

Comment: Google "Where is RSA used?" and you'll get answers already existing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is true.  RSA is an encryption algorithm.

Example uses:

1. SSL
2. SSH
3. Digital signatures
4. PGP

Answer (score 0):

RSA is used in cryptography in Key-based authentication.SSH uses this method of key generation as it is considered very secure.

[see here for more](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)